# Does Illustrator have Mouse Wheel selection like Inkscape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, selections

Does Adobe Illustrator have Inkscape-like (since version 0.91) `Alt + Mouse Wheel` selection mode?

Answer (score 0):

No, Illustrator does not have a mouse wheel selection mode.